# Polkit Rule `systemctl enable`

Tags: systemctl, polkit

How to write a rule so that an unprivileged user has the rights to execute the command `systemctl enable my.service` and only for `my.service`?

I was able to give the rights to `systemctl start/stop my.service`
But `systemctl enable` so far it turns out to allow only for all services

```
  var allowedActions = [
          "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files"
  ];

  polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
          polkit.log("action=" + action);
          polkit.log("subject=" + subject);

          if (allowedActions.includes(action.id) &&
          subject.user == "myUser")
          {
                  polkit.log("!!!!!!");
                  return polkit.Result.YES;
          }
  });
```

For `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units` has the value `unit`, and for `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files` - no such value